# IPython and unittests, fixed tests don't show as fixed

Tags: python, unit-testing, ipython

I'm just starting to use IPython. I like it a lot, and was looking forward to using the `%run` magic method to run unit tests without dropping out of the shell. So I tried:

```
In [30]: run runTests.py
```

Which, as far as I could tell worked great, running the tests as I had described in the `runTests.py` file. However, the output showed me that I had failing tests:

```
Ran 16 tests in 0.156s

FAILED (failures=3)
```

So I dug in to my code and fixed the problem, and headed back to IPython to run the tests again:

```
In [31]: run runTests.py
```

However, this reported that I still had failing tests:

```
Ran 16 tests in 0.141s

FAILED (failures=3)
```

Running the tests outside of IPython showed that I actually had fixed them. The IPython documentation seems to state that any changes to my code should be reflected any time I use `%run`:

> The %run magic command allows you to run any python script and load all of its data directly into the interactive namespace. Since the file is re-read from disk each time, changes you make to it are reflected immediately.

So my question is, what gives? Does it matter that the modules that my tests are importing are loaded in to IPython? I tried `autoreload`, but that didn't help either. I would love to be able to quickly run my unit tests from IPython so I would appreciate any direction on the best way to do that.

Comment: I had the same problem, autoreload 2 did work...what value were you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I guess this is because your imported modules don't get reloaded between runs.

Autoreload should help with this. Read [the docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) and check that you're using it correctly. Note that it can't reload compiled C extensions. Of course, it's possible that autoreload has a bug, so if you're convinced that you're doing it right, ask on [the mailing list](http://projects.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-user) or [file a bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: Any clue as to _why_ they don't get reloaded between runs? Is it because "changes you make to it are reflected immediately" means only _that file_?

Comment: Yes. %run makes no attempt to reload imported modules that your script might use.

Comment: The dreload function in iPython may work for you; dreload(file) reloads file.py and all modules that file.py imports, and all the ones they import, and so on. It takes time to do all of this reloading, but it works reliably..